# How to call original function with "one less" C-u?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I want to override some basic function, let's say save-buffer (even if it does not make sense, it's for the sake of clarity), and give it a new definition. But I want all the original behaviors to be callable by adding a C-u.

So,

- C-x C-s become my new definition of save-buffer.
- C-u C-x C-s would call the original C-x C-s (without argument)
- C-u C-u C-x C-s would be same same as calling the original C-x C-s with *one* C-u

and so on: always "one less" C-u...

Right now, I test for the value of arg. If nil, I execute my new defintion; otherwise, I call-interactively save-buffer (for the example). But, then, save-buffer is called with one C-u argument. I don't see how to do the "-1" C-u part.

Comment: How are you calling the original function from your new defintiion?  (Please show code, if possible.)

Comment: If you haven't already, have a look at [21.12 Prefix Command Arguments](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html) for some information how to access prefix arguments, and how set them up for the next call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
(defun foo (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (message "foo %s" arg))

(defun bar (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (message "bar %s" arg))

(defmacro wrap (fg f g)
  `(defun ,fg (arg)
     (interactive "p")
     (message "%s" arg)
     (if (= 1 arg)
         (funcall ,g 1)
       (funcall ,f (/ arg 4)))))

(wrap baz #'foo #'bar)
```

Now a plain `baz` will call `bar`. With <kbd>C-u</kbd>
it will call `foo`, dividing the given arg by 4.